# How to make Mailspring default mail app?

Tags: settings, release-juno, pantheon-mail, switchboard

I installed the snap version of Mailspring (using Snaptastic), but during install the `.desktop` file for some reason wasn't copied to `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` . I did that manually (to both locations) and now the icon is working and it's appearing in the Applications launcher, yet when I go to *System Settings -> Applications*, Mailspring isn't listed as an option under "Email Client". How can I fix this so that `mailto:` links go to Mailspring instead of Pantheon Mail?

When I tried the `.deb` version this worked flawlessly.

[image: Mailspring option missing from Email Client menu]

[image: Mailspring appears in applications launcher]

Here's the contents of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mailspring
Comment=The best email app for people and teams at work
GenericName=Mailspring
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mailspring_mailspring.desktop /snap/bin/mailspring %U
Icon=/snap/mailspring/309/usr/share/pixmaps/mailspring.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Mailspring
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;Email;
Keywords=email;internet;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;x-scheme-handler/mailspring;
```

Comment: Hi mr.k99, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have made some edits to make your question look better but your choice of words and format DO describe your problem well. Here's a little **tip:** When you add *keywords* or *commands* in your question, answer & comment, mark them as *code*.

Comment: What's the content of the desktop file you added? Does it include `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;x-scheme-handler/mailspring;`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the contents of the `.desktop`. Yes, it does indeed include that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes to desktop files manually, you often have to run:

`sudo update-desktop-database`

This can also be pointed at your local user's desktop database like so:

`update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications`

And changes to mime types often need the following:

`sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

Although the `update-mime-database` command is not likely necessary in this case, as that's usually needed when new mime types are registered rather than adding new applications to existing mimes.